# Is it possible to access another blazor circuit?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Is it possible to access another blazor server side circuit from an browser client?

Let's say I want to look on the screen of an user, because he needs some help.
The user clicks a "support" button and tells me an id. With that id I connect to the session of the user and we can see the same screen (or better dom).

Answer (score 1):

Blazor can only watch components/elements that generated by itself.

So, to mirror the user screen, you don't need blazor. Instead, you can use SignalR or any realtime framework messaging that help you stream the whole DOM then render again on your side.

Comment: Yes, but afaik blazor server side already has the dom and also processes the dom changes

Comment: If the DOM is trigged to change by blazor, it knows otherwise it cannot know

Comment: We also can say that blazor has dom of anything inside Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>, not outside. PS: for the same reason above, not 100%